# Can't cast void pointer returned by RegGetValueA

Tags: c++, registry, void-pointers

I'm trying to access the registry using the RegGetValueA function, but I can't cast the void pointer passed to the function. I just get the (value?) of the pointer itself.

Here's my code:

```
    LSTATUS res;
    LPCSTR lpSubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{071c9b48-7c32-4621-a0ac-3f809523288f}";
    LPCSTR lpValue = "InstallSource";
    PVOID pvData = new PVOID;
    LPDWORD pcbData = new DWORD;

    res = RegGetValueA(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        lpSubKey,
        lpValue,
        RRF_RT_ANY,
        NULL,
        pvData,
        pcbData);

    string* data = static_cast<string*>(pvData);
    cout << data << "\n";
    cout << pvData;
```

output:

```
000000000045A240
000000000045A240
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

link to documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluea

Comment: `PVOID pvData = new PVOID; LPDWORD pcbData = new DWORD;` why? Try `char buffer[256]; DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer); RegGetValueA(...
        buffer,
        &bufferSize);`

Comment: @fabian I tried this, however passing a char array to RegGetValueA causes it to fail as it only accepts void pointers.

Comment: @RichardCritten pdwType is a REG_SZ, which according to the documentation is a null terminated string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types

Comment: The Win32 API never returns a `std::string` (or any other C++ class; it's a C API). You need to pass it a memory buffer that's large enough.

Comment: @kkk A `char*` can be implicitly converted to `void*`, so you must have misinterpreted something.

Comment: @molbdnilo even when I cast the void pointer(pvData) to a char* it still has the same value as the pointer. I guess the problem here is that I don't know how to correctly cast pvData to another data type.

Comment: You shouldn't cast anything at all, or use `new`, you should do as in the topmost comment.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm not sure I understand. How can I pass a char array to the function when the parameter type is void*?

Comment: The array is implicitly converted into a pointer to its first element, which is implicitly converted to `void*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the function incorrectly.

First off, you shouldn't be accessing `Wow6432Node` directly at all. The function has flags for accessing 32bit and 64bit keys when dealing with WOW64.

More importantly, you are giving the function a `void*` pointer that doesn't point at valid memory for your purpose. When reading a string value from the Registry, you must pre-allocate a character buffer of sufficient size, then pass the address of that buffer to the function. You can ask the function for the necessary buffer size.

The code should look more like the following instead:

```
LSTATUS res;
LPCSTR lpSubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{071c9b48-7c32-4621-a0ac-3f809523288f}";
LPCSTR lpValue = "InstallSource";
char *pszData = NULL;
DWORD cbData = 0;

res = RegGetValueA( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKey, lpValue, RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6432KEY, NULL, NULL, &cbData);
if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) ...

pszData = new char[cbData];
res = RegGetValueA( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKey, lpValue, RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6432KEY, NULL, pszData, &cbData);
if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS) ...

cout << pszData << "\n";
delete[] pszData;
```